# Imported chart gets cropped in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint

When importing charts from an Excel-file, parts of the chartarea gets left out when pasting it into PowerPoint as a linked object. I've tried resizing both the area holding the linked chart and the slides, but nothing seems to work. Is there any way to fix this?
[image]
The x-axis here is supposed to go to 53, but as you can see there are about 11 values missing. The bottom of of the chart isn't visible either.

Comment: Have you re-sized the original before copying?

Comment: Can you upload the Source sheet, so that I can make a Chart using Original values and Paste it to PP, to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Not a direct fix**

I have 2 work arounds that I use when faced with the same issue.

1) Try pasting into MS word first, Then copy and paste into PP,

2) Paste the chart as an image into PP,